# Dropmenu with if clauses

Tags: grails

I am trying to make my dropmenu whenever I select the number 30 to print hello,however it always shows Hello,any idea why it doesn't work

```
     <g:select name="user.age" from="${18..65}" value="${age}"
              noSelection="['':'-Choose your age-']"/>


      <g:if test="${age==30} ">
             Hello
            </g:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be `<g:if test="${user.age==30} ">`. The problem here is as per your last post, a user changing the value of a select box on the front end has not been registered or sent to your grails controller. When you next do `<g:if` It is checking the same value as was provided by your controller in the instance of 
`<g:select name="user.age" from="${18..65}" value="${age}"` age here.. again this is wrong since you have called name `user.age`

So unless your g:select on change submits it to the controller then your gsp is reloaded so `<g:if test="${user.age==30} ">` can now pickup the new value.

It is a static value received by your view at the time controller called it VS your user dynamically changing the content of the select box. For which the change behaviour is handled by jquery as explained in previous answer to your previous question